# Why does the well ordering principle involve positive integers in it's statement?

Tags: number-theory

> Well ordering principle: Every nonempty set of nonnegative integers has a smallest element.

Why is it that it's only non negative? If you consider the set $\{-1,-2,-3 \}$ then it is clear than the smallest is $-3$. So, why must it be that strictly it is non negative?

### My thoughts:

The only issue I see happening is if we have an infintie set $ \{-1,-2... \}$ but then we can fix the definition by making it only apply to finite sets if negative integers are included, correct?

Comment: I think you've already answered your question. A nonempty set of integers does not necessarily have a minimal element. The fact that a finite set of integers has a minimal element is not quite as interesting, since that is true for any finite set of a totally ordered set.

Comment: A possible statement for integers is: Every nonempty set of integers that is bounded below has a smallest element.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I will convert both your comments into an answer when I am more learned.